# Attaching events to controllers in a telerik template column

Tags: asp.net, telerik-grid

I have a telerik grid which includes a template column hosting a dropdownlist.

I need to attach the event `selectedIndexChnaged` for that dropdownList.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the below link where telerik support explains it.

[Telerik Support](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet/grid/dropdownlist-selectedindexchange-event-on-radgrid.aspx)